# Client and Server Android Socket Connection

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm not familiar with java, and I'm trying to do two Android application that communicates with each other (Client application, and Server application). On Client application, *I want to display the Server IP,* but it doesn't work with this:

```
     for(i=1;i<=254;i++)
             {    s1=partialip+String.valueOf(i);
    //partialip has the form: "a.b.c."
    //in s1 there are all possible Server's IPs : "192.168.1.1" or "192.168.1.2"...     


                 InetAddress serv = InetAddress.getByName(s1); 
                 Socket socket = new Socket(serv, 5000);
                 if(socket.isConnected()==true)
                 {
                          String server_ip = new String(s1);
                     text2.setText("Server IP: " + server_ip);
                          break;
                 } 




         }
```

I will appreciate it if somebody will help me.

Comment: Debug your app to ensure whether this socket connection returning true/false

Comment: if not connected, `new Socket()` takes a fair amount of time (about 2-3 minutes) unless the small timeout has been specified. so considering the fact that you're doing this for 254 addresses, the worst case is 254*3 minutes of waiting if there is no connection at all

Comment: program logic is correct though

Comment: Ah, you are right, this method is not fast. Can you give me another example to display the Server ip on the Client application?

Answer (score 0):

To find a server on a local network, you'd better use UDP broadcast (DatagramSocket).